# Using webpack dependency management in a loader through html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, nunjucks, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-file-loader

I'm currently trying to add a feature to the [`nunjucks-isomorphic-loader`](https://github.com/SudoCat/Nunjucks-Isomorphic-Loader) . The goal here is to allow using require statements inside templates so webpack would load and bundle them. It also have to work using the `html-webpack-plugin`

So after reading [the webpack docs about module dependencies](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#module-dependencies) I chose to use the following syntax inside the templates: `{{ require('path/to/asset.jpg') }}` as it is valid nunjucks syntax considering `require` as a macro.

Then I started coding a bit on the loader and ended with the following modifications:

from :

```
var precompiledTemplates = nunjucks.precompile(paths[0], {
    env: env,
    include: [/.*\.(njk|nunjucks|html|tpl|tmpl)$/]
});
```

to :

```
var templateContent = fs.readFileSync(name, { encoding: 'utf8' });

// Search for require macros
templateAsString = templateContent.replace(
    /\{\{\s*require\([\'\"]{1}(.+)[\'\"]{1}\)\s*\}\}/,
    function (match, $1) {
        return require(path.resolve(paths[0], $1));
    }
);

var precompiledTemplates = nunjucks.precompileString(templateAsString, {
    name: name,
    env: env,
    include: [/.*\.(njk|nunjucks|html|tpl|tmpl)$/]
});
```

So here I simply get the template content to replace the require statements by actual requires so webpack would load the assets.

But here's the issue: using this with html-webpack-plugin doesn't seem to use the loaders I defined in my `webpack.config.js`.

Here's my testing config:

```
/
├── asset.jpg
├── index.js
├── test.njk
├── webpack.config.js
```

index.js is empty.

test.njk:

```
test template
{{ require('./asset.jpg') }}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './index.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Javascript
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      //   use: {
      //     loader: 'babel-loader'
      //   }
      // },

      // Nunjucks - HTML
      {
        test: /\.njk$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'nunjucks-isomorphic-loader',
            query: {
              root: [path.resolve(__dirname, '')]
            }
          }
        ]
      },

      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(jpe*g|png)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][hash:8].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      tplVars: {
        foo: 'bar'
      },
      filename: path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'),
      template: 'test.njk'
    })
  ],

  resolveLoader: {
    // This allows to actually use the loader with is outside of node_modules
    modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, '../')]
  },

  devtool: 'eval',

  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get when webpack builds:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./test.njk
    Module build failed: /Users/gomoon/Documents/workspace/Sandbox/nunjucks-tests/asset.jpg:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����
                                                                  ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:576:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at /Users/gomoon/Documents/workspace/Sandbox/nunjucks-isomorphic-loader/src/node-loader.js:61:11
        at String.replace (<anonymous>)
        at Object.module.exports (/Users/gomoon/Documents/workspace/Sandbox/nunjucks-isomorphic-loader/src/node-loader.js:56:37)
        at Object.module.exports (/Users/gomoon/Documents/workspace/Sandbox/nunjucks-isomorphic-loader/index.js:16:44)
```

Showing that it imports the `.jpg` file "as is" and not with the `file-loader` I defined in the webpack config file.

So, I'm stuck here and I'm not even sure what I try to accomplish is actually possible.

More details can be found in [this issue on the official repo](https://github.com/SudoCat/Nunjucks-Isomorphic-Loader/issues/3)

Comment: AFAIR plugins not use loaders section in config. At least HTML plugin, webpack do it like the following: prepare js code,  run plugins. it is separate action. May be specifing loader in require statement will help.

Comment: It looks like html-webpack-plugin does not support the `module.rules` loader syntax, only the old `module.loaders` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried with the `loaders` syntax but the result is the same.